# Tkinter adding X and Y scroll bars to full app

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to add scroll bars in my Tkinter UI and have an interesting problem. I first added the y bar and it works fine. It fills vertically, scrolls the whole window, and even bound the scroll bar to mousewheel. However when adding the xbar, it does not fill horizontally. It still 'scrolls' by just clicking the arrow buttons that show, but the bar is stuck in the bottom right corner.

[image: Here is the image that shows my issue]

Here is the code that generates the scrollbars in my app:

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # initialize parent class for the child

        ...

        # defining containers
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # scrollbar
        self.app_canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
        self.app_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        self.scrollbarX = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient='horizontal', command=self.app_canvas.xview)
        self.scrollbarX.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
        self.scrollbarY = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient='vertical', command=self.app_canvas.yview)
        self.scrollbarY.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.app_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbarY.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbarX.set)
        
        self.inner_frame = tk.Frame(self.app_canvas)
        self.inner_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.update_scrollregion())
        self.app_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.inner_frame, anchor='nw')
        self.inner_frame.bind("<Enter>", self.bind_mousewheel)
        self.inner_frame.bind("<Leave>", self.unbind_mousewheel)
```

and the update scrollregion function:

```
def update_scrollregion(self):
        self.app_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.app_canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: The order that you call pack matters. Pack the scrollbars before the canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley wouldn't neither of the scrollbars work if that was the issue?

Comment: No, not necessarily.

Comment: That seemed to fix it! Thank you for the help, post this as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which you call `pack` on widgets matters. When you call `pack`, it will reserve an entire side of the available space. Nothing else will be able to occupy that side. In other words, you aren't packing to a side of a window, you are packing to a side of unused space.

In your case you're packing the canvas first, and asking that it be packed to the left. That means that nothing else can touch the entire left side. The only available space will be to the right of the canvas.

You next pack the horizontal scrollbar on the bottom. Because the left side has already been filled, the only available space is to the right of the canvas. When you pack it to the bottom, it's the bottom *of the available space*, not the bottom of the window as a whole. So, it appears to the right of the canvas, and at the bottom.

Finally, you pack the vertical scrollbar on the top. Since the only available space is now to the right of the canvas and above the horizontal scrollbar, that's where it appears.

What you can do instead is first pack the horizontal scrollbar on the bottom, and the vertical scrollbar on the right before packing the canvas. You'll get a slightly different effect depending on which scrollbar is packed first.

For example, this puts the horizontal scrollbar below the vertical scrollbar:

```
self.scrollbarX.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
self.scrollbarY.pack(side='right', fill='y')
self.app_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
```

[image: screenshot 1]

By reversing the order that the scrollbars are packed you'll get a slightly different arrangement, with the horizontal scrollbar to the left of the vertical scrollbar:

```
self.scrollbarY.pack(side='right', fill='y')
self.scrollbarX.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
self.app_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
```

[image: screenshot 2]

With all that being said, I would argue that `grid` is the better tool when laying out scrollbars. With `grid`  you can prevent one of the scrollbars from being on top or to the side of the other scrollbar. With `grid` it's possible to leave a little unused square to the right of the horizontal scrollbar and below the vertical scrollbar.

Using `grid` requires a couple extra statements to tell grid how to allocate any extra space (for example, when the user resizes the window).

```
container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

self.app_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
self.scrollbarX.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")
self.scrollbarY.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
```

Note: it's perfectly find to mix `grid` and `pack` in an application. The only restriction is you can't use both for widgets that have the same parent.

[image: screenshot 3]

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
    # Scrollbar
    self.app_canvas = tk.Canvas(container)
    self.app_canvas.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
    self.scrollbarX = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient='horizontal', command=self.app_canvas.xview)
    self.scrollbarX.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')
    self.scrollbarY = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient='vertical', command=self.app_canvas.yview)
    self.scrollbarY.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    self.app_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbarY.set, xscrollcommand=self.scrollbarX.set)

    self.inner_frame = tk.Frame(self.app_canvas)
    self.app_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.inner_frame, anchor='nw')

    # Bind the scrollbar to the canvas
    self.inner_frame.bind("<Configure>", self.update_scrollregion)

def update_scrollregion(self, event=None):
    self.app_canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.app_canvas.bbox("all"))

def bind_mousewheel(self, event):
    self.app_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mousewheel)

def unbind_mousewheel(self, event):
    self.app_canvas.unbind_all("<MouseWheel>")

def on_mousewheel(self, event):
    self.app_canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
```

Comment: didn't work, just removed the scrolling ability. Can you explain what you changed and what it was supposed to do?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).